# not getting any data from Yahoo Finance using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, yahoo-finance

i want to create a web page that makes ajax request using jQuery to get stock prices from the following yahoo web service...

```
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=04&b=13&c=1995&d=04&e=23&f=1995&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

my internet connection if fairly speedy..but i dont get any data...from the above URL..

always `"OnError:" jQuery part is executed.....`
i tried a lot...does my request time out....??

Comment: are you sure the service allows cross-domain requests?

Comment: i have hosted this webpage on my local machine...i have installed XAMPP,,

Comment: i am talking about the yahoo web service from where you want to fetch results

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will be able to make request to other domains using AJAX (for example as you have hosted on your own machine, you will be allowed to make request to URLs on http://localhost/ only) .

Someone has already created an API for it. You can get it from here http://www.goldb.org/ystockquote.html
You can use it either in your web-app or from your local machine.

If you want to make a web-app,a solution would be to make a small proxy using the python module which will make request to the url with the parameters given by you and return the response.You can try using App Engine for this. If you are using other languages like PHP you can easily convert the functions given in the module to your own language.